# How to change just folder color for top parent node not nested parent node in angular mat tree

Tags: node.js, angular, angular-material, angular-cdk

Goal : Only change the parent node to BLUE color and not the nested parent node(which is yellow)

We are trying to change the color of the just parent node in the mat tree and not the nested parent node. If the change the color of the parent node, it is also affecting the nested parent tree node.
Is there to identify only the top node not the nested top parent tree to affected the folder color like shown in the below diagram.

[image]

```
<mat-tree [dataSource]="nestedDataSource" [treeControl]="nestedTreeControl" class="protocol-tree">
        <mat-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node" matTreeNodeToggle>
            <li class="mat-tree-node">
                <div class="type-icon">
                    <span *ngIf="node.location === null; else file" class="folder-color">
                        <img src="./../../../../../assets/icons/MaterialIconFolder.svg">
                    </span>
                    <ng-template #file>
                        <img src="./../../../../../assets/icons/MaterialIconDraft.svg">
                    </ng-template>
                </div>


                <span class="file-text">
                    <div *ngIf="node.location === null; else fileText">
                        {{ capitalizeFirstLetter(node.name) }}
                    </div>
                    <ng-template #fileText>
                        <a (click)="downloadProtocolDocuments(node)">{{ node.name }}</a>
                    </ng-template>

                </span>
            </li>
        </mat-tree-node>

        <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; when: hasNestedChild">
            <li>
                <div class="mat-tree-node">
                    <div class="type-icon">
                    <span *ngIf="node.location === null; else file" class="folder-color">
                        <img src="./../../../../../assets/icons/MaterialIconFolder.svg">
                    </span>
                    <ng-template #file>
                        <img src="./../../../../../assets/icons/MaterialIconDraft.svg">
                    </ng-template>
                    </div>


                    <span class="file-text">
                        {{ capitalizeFirstLetter(node.name) }}
                    </span>
                    <button mat-icon-button matTreeNodeToggle [attr.aria-label]="'toggle ' + node.name">
                        <mat-icon class="mat-icon-rtl-mirror">
                            {{
                            nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)
                            ? "expand_less"
                            : "expand_more"
                            }}
                        </mat-icon>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <ul [class.protocol-tree-invisible]="!nestedTreeControl.isExpanded(node)">
                    <ng-container matTreeNodeOutlet></ng-container>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </mat-nested-tree-node>
    </mat-tree>
</div>
```

Help is appreciated !

Comment: It looks like you're applying the class `folder-color` to both `mat-tree-node` and `mat-nested-tree-node`. Could you simply use a different class with the desired styling?

Comment: @BizzyBob i Did try that but it is still affected all nested folders too

Comment: What does your css look like? You should be able to select for just the parent folder.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2tsce2?file=app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.html,app%2Ftree-nested-overview-example.css

Comment: I created a sample css in stackblitz. top parent should be blue and nested should be yellow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i was able get it resolved using level property

```
  <mat-nested-tree-node *matTreeNodeDef="let node; let l=level; when: hasChild">
```

https://angular-2tsce2-l7qhtt.stackblitz.io